# How to set the order in which administrative accounts are offered in UAC prompts?

Tags: windows, windows-10, administrator, uac

I have installed Windows 10 Enterprise 1909 on several of my PCs. For my daily work, I am using an account which is **not** in the `Administrators` group. This means that I am running into UAC prompts quite often, which somehow is the goal of working that way.

So far, so good. But when working as a non-administrator, the UAC prompt not only asks you to click `YES` to permit the respective action, but you have to enter an administrator's password. If there are multiple administrative users on the system, this can lead to problems.

For example, the UAC prompt in my daily work account looks like that:

[image: UAC prompt stage 1]

Here, we can see that there obviously is an administrative user `Acronis Agent User` on that system, which is not surprising because I have installed Acronis software there. However, I can't enter the password of this user, because I don't know it; that account has been created automatically during Acronis software installation and might be configured without a password at all.

Hence, to proceed, I have to click on the link `More choices`, which in turn leads to the following situation:

[image: UAC prompt stage 2]

I want to use the Administrator password, because it is the only administrative password I know, so I have to click again on `Administrator`, which leads to the following situation:

[image: UAC prompt stage 3]

Now I finally can enter the `Administrator` password and click `YES`.

This whole procedure is driving me mad now (after having tolerated it for several months). I hit that UAC prompt several times a day, and it takes several mouse clicks until I finally can enter the password. There is no chance to automate the procedure because the UAC prompt appears on a `Secure Desktop`, which I don't want to change.

Hence the question:

Is it possible to set a "default administrative user for UAC prompts" somewhere, or to order the list of administrative accounts which are offered in the UAC prompt? If I could make `Administrator` the first list item (instead of `Acronis Agent User`), the problem would be solved.

It seems that the list is sorted alphabetically, so I could eventually rename the `Administrator` account name to `000`, for example. But I have never tried this and I am unsure whether or not it would be a stupid idea, so I would prefer to order that account list using another method; perhaps the order is somewhere in the registry or something like that.

Any ideas?

Comment: really well asked question – but [Windows 10 UAC prompt default to particular admin user](https://superuser.com/a/1547768/82869) seems to already have an answer: it's usernames alphabetically (not display names)

Comment: Thank you very much for bringing that other question to my attention, and +1. You are right - it is the very same question, and I have missed it. However, I am not very happy with the answer given there, because creating an additional administrative account just for the purpose of UAC sounds kind of silly. The OP seems to agree with me and didn't accept the answer yet. Plus, there is a dispute below the answer about whether or not that problem could be solved without doing this; the parties involved claim different behavior, and it is not clear who of them is right.

Comment: I guess I'll rather rename `Administrator` to something else (e.g. `000`) than create a new administrative account. But perhaps there are still chances that somebody provides a reasonable solution within the next days. I'll just wait some time and then decide about it (and eventually update my question).

Comment: I hear you about it driving you mad. I set fingerprint logging for my admin account with a different/unused finger and to my surprise it works at the UAC prompt.